# Non-recursive topological ordering, starting from given nodes, for Guava graphs

Tags: java, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, graph

This method returns the topological ordering of a [Guava graph](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#graph) starting from a given set of nodes. It's from my personal project [github.com/jbduncan/guava-graph-utils](https://github.com/jbduncan/guava-graph-utils), where I'm exploring utilities for Guava graphs. I'm aware of JGraphT, which has a topological ordering iterator that can be used with Guava graphs, but I'm reinventing the wheel purely for fun.

I'm open to any feedback, but I'm particularly keen for feedback on the inner `DeepRecursion` class. It was inspired by [`Iteration`](https://github.com/google/mug/blob/master/mug/src/main/java/com/google/mu/util/stream/Iteration.java) from [github.com/google/mug](https://github.com/google/mug) and Kotlin's [`DeepRecursiveFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deep-recursive-function/), and it turns the underlying depth-first-search-based algorithm from a recursive one to an iterative one to let it run on large inputs. However, I wonder if there's a simpler, easier to read solution, or even a faster one.

Note: this is a stripped-down version of the file with just the relevant method; the Javadoc refers to other methods in the [same file](https://github.com/jbduncan/guava-graph-utils/blob/984107493270afca931654bf7f8f1d5ee3ffb39a/src/main/java/com/github/jbduncan/guavagraphutils/MoreGraphs.java), so refer to it if you're interested.

```java
package com.github.jbduncan.guavagraphutils;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.graph.Graph;
import com.google.common.graph.SuccessorsFunction;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

// This class purposefully expands upon an unstable Guava API
@SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")
public final class MoreGraphs {

  private static final String SUCCESSORS_FUNCTION_HAS_AT_LEAST_ONE_CYCLE =
      "successors function has at least one cycle";

  /**
   * Returns an immutable list representing the topological ordering of the graph, specifically the
   * subgraph that is {@linkplain com.google.common.graph.Graphs#reachableNodes(Graph, Object)
   * reachable} from the given starting nodes. A topological ordering is a traversal of the subgraph
   * in which each node is visited only after all its {@linkplain Graph#predecessors(Object)
   * predecessors} and other ancestors have been visited.
   *
   * <p>This method is preferable to {@link MoreGraphs#lazyTopologicalOrdering(Graph)
   * lazyTopologicalOrdering} and {@link MoreGraphs#topologicalOrdering(Graph) topologicalOrdering}
   * when the graph can only be represented as a successors function or when only the subgraph
   * reachable from the starting nodes is needed.
   *
   * <p>The given starting nodes iterable, its elements, and the graph must all be non-null,
   * otherwise a {@code NullPointerException} will be thrown.
   *
   * <p>The given graph may have multiple valid topological orderings. This method does not
   * guarantee which topological ordering is returned, even on subsequent calls.
   *
   * <p>For example, given this graph and starting node {@code a}...
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * b <--- a ---> d   g ---> h
   * |      |                 |
   * v      v                 v
   * e ---> c ---> f          i
   * }</pre>
   *
   * <p>...the topological ordering returned can be any of:
   *
   * <ul>
   *   <li>{@code [a, b, d, e, c, f]}
   *   <li>{@code [a, b, e, c, d, f]}
   *   <li>{@code [a, b, e, d, c, f]}
   *   <li>{@code [a, b, e, c, f, d]}
   *   <li>{@code [a, d, b, e, c, f]}
   * </ul>
   *
   * <p>Note that the subgraph {@code {g, h, i}} is not reachable from node {@code a}. Thus, its
   * nodes are not included in the topological ordering.
   *
   * <p>This method only works on directed acyclic graphs. If a cycle is discovered when traversing
   * the graph, an {@code IllegalArgumentException} will be thrown.
   *
   * <p>This method runs in linear time, specifically {@code O(N + E)}, where {@code N} is the
   * number of nodes in the graph and {@code E} is the number of edges.
   *
   * @param startingNodes the nodes to start traversing the graph from; the iterable and the nodes
   *     themselves must not be null
   * @param successorsFunction the graph to return a topological ordering for; must not be null
   * @param <N> the node type; must have {@link #equals(Object) equals()} and {@link #hashCode()
   *     hashCode()} implementations as described in "<a
   *     href='https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#graph-elements-nodes-and-edges'>
   *     Graphs Explained</a>".
   * @return an immutable list representing a topological ordering of the graph
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the graph has a cycle
   * @see <a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting'>Wikipedia, "Topological
   *     sorting"</a>
   * @see <a href='https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained'>Graphs Explained</a>
   */
  public static <N> ImmutableList<N> topologicalOrderingStartingFrom(
      Iterable<N> startingNodes, SuccessorsFunction<N> successorsFunction) {
    checkNotNull(startingNodes, "startingNodes");
    for (N startingNode : startingNodes) {
      checkNotNull(startingNode, "startingNodes has at least one null node");
    }
    checkNotNull(successorsFunction, "successorsFunction");

    /*
     * Depth-first-search-based algorithm. Derived from [1], in turn derived from Introduction to Algorithms (2nd ed.)
     * by Cormen et al.
     *
     * The original algorithm by Cormen et al. is recursive, which may throw StackOverflowErrors on large inputs, so
     * this algorithm uses an iterative "deep recursion" technique to simulate the stack and avoid SOEs.
     *
     * [1] https://web.archive.org/web/20230225053309/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search
     */

    abstract class DeepRecursion<T> {
      @FunctionalInterface
      interface Closure {
        void run();
      }

      private final Deque<Object> intermediateStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
      private final Deque<Object> frameStack = new ArrayDeque<>();

      void yieldClosure(Closure closure) {
        intermediateStack.push(closure);
      }

      void yieldValue(T value) {
        intermediateStack.push(value);
      }

      ImmutableList<T> recurse() {
        return Stream.generate(this::next)
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull) // null signals end of data
            .collect(toImmutableList())
            .reverse();
      }

      private @Nullable T next() {
        while (true) {
          while (!intermediateStack.isEmpty()) {
            frameStack.push(intermediateStack.pop());
          }

          if (!frameStack.isEmpty()) {
            var next = frameStack.pop();
            if (next instanceof Closure closure) {
              closure.run();
            } else {
              // frameStack only contains Ns and Closures, so the type is
              // guaranteed to be N here.
              @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              T result = (T) next;
              return result;
            }
          }

          if (intermediateStack.isEmpty() && frameStack.isEmpty()) {
            return null; // end of data
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class DeepRecursiveTopo extends DeepRecursion<N> {
      private enum VisitState {
        PARTIALLY_VISITED,
        FULLY_VISITED
      }

      DeepRecursiveTopo() {
        var nodeToVisitState = new HashMap<N, VisitState>();
        for (N startingNode : startingNodes) {
          yieldClosure(() -> visit(startingNode, successorsFunction, nodeToVisitState));
        }
      }

      private void visit(
          N node, SuccessorsFunction<N> successorsFunction, Map<N, VisitState> nodeToVisitState) {
        var visitState = nodeToVisitState.get(node);
        if (visitState == VisitState.FULLY_VISITED) {
          return;
        }
        if (visitState == VisitState.PARTIALLY_VISITED) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(SUCCESSORS_FUNCTION_HAS_AT_LEAST_ONE_CYCLE);
        }

        nodeToVisitState.put(node, VisitState.PARTIALLY_VISITED);

        for (N successor : successorsFunction.successors(node)) {
          yieldClosure(() -> visit(successor, successorsFunction, nodeToVisitState));
        }

        yieldClosure(() -> nodeToVisitState.put(node, VisitState.FULLY_VISITED));
        yieldValue(node);
      }
    }

    return new DeepRecursiveTopo().recurse();
  }

  private MoreGraphs() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, the only things I can think of are:

- Remove the `successorsFunction` and `nodeToVisitState` parameters from `DeepRecursiveTopo.visit()`, which either aren't needed or can be fields.
- Make `DeepRecursion` and `DeepRecursiveTopo` non-local classes to reduce clutter.
- Research how others have done iterative depth-first-search-based topological ordering. (Or ask a LLM and thoroughly test it.)

  - But I'm actually quite fond of the deep recursion technique, so this would be a last resort.